# how to bind the Menu template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database, vb.net

I want to display Multilevel Menu
My Coding Like

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Session("UserName") IsNot Nothing Then
            lbl1.Text = "Welcome  " & Convert.ToString(Session("UserName"))
        End If

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sample").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select MenuID, Menus from PagesDetails", con)
        Dim dttc As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dttc)
        Dim main As HtmlGenericControl = UList("Menuid", "menu")
        Dim dtDist As New DataTable()
        Dim Flag As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In dttc.Rows

            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            dtDist.Clear()
            cmd.CommandText = "FindMenus"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToString(Session("UserId"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row("MenuID").ToString()
            data.SelectCommand = cmd
            data.Fill(dtDist)
            If dtDist.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim sub_menu As HtmlGenericControl = LIList(row("Menus").ToString(), row("MenuID").ToString(), "")
                Dim ul As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
                Dim mains As HtmlGenericControl = UList("SubMenuId", "menu")
                For Each r As DataRow In dtDist.Rows

                    ul.Controls.Add(LIList(r("SubMenu").ToString(), r("SubMenuId").ToString(), ""))
                    If r IsNot Nothing Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                        Dim dtsub As New DataTable
                        Dim data1 As New SqlDataAdapter
                        cmd.CommandText = "Menusfind"
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToString(Session("UserId"))
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row("MenuID").ToString()
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubMenuId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = r("SubMenuId").ToString()
                        data1.SelectCommand = cmd
                        data1.Fill(dtsub)
                        Dim ul1 As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")

                        If dtsub.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                            Dim sub_menu2 As HtmlGenericControl = LIList(r("SubMenu").ToString(), r("SubMenuId").ToString(), "arrow")
                            sub_menu.Controls.Add(ul)
                            sub_menu2.Controls.Add(ul1)
                            mains.Controls.Add(sub_menu2)
                        Else
                            Dim sub_menu2 As HtmlGenericControl = LIList(r("SubMenu").ToString(), r("SubMenuId").ToString(), "drop")
                            For Each r1 As DataRow In dtsub.Rows
                                ul1.Controls.Add(LIList(r1("SubMenu2").ToString(), r1("SMenu2Id").ToString(), ""))
                            Next
                            sub_menu2.Controls.Add(ul1)
                            mains.Controls.Add(sub_menu2)
                        End If
                    Else

                    End If

                Next
                sub_menu.Controls.Add(mains)
                'sub_menu.Controls.Add(ul)
                main.Controls.Add(sub_menu)

            Else
                If row("Menus") = "Home" Or row("Menus") = "About" Then
                    main.Controls.Add(LIList(row("Menus").ToString(), row("Menuid").ToString(), ""))
                Else

                End If

            End If
        Next
        Panel1.Controls.Add(main)
    End Sub
    Private Function UList(ByVal id As String, ByVal cssClass As String) As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim ul As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
        ul.ID = id
        ul.Attributes.Add("class", cssClass)

        Return ul
    End Function
    Private Function LIList(ByVal innerHtml As String, ByVal rel As String, ByVal cssClass As String) As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim li As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
        li.Attributes.Add("rel", rel)
        li.InnerHtml = (Convert.ToString("<a href=" + ">") & innerHtml) + "</a>"
        li.Attributes.Add("class", cssClass)
        Return li

    End Function
    Protected Sub login1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles login1.Click
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

It will display the Correct Multilevel Menu,, I binding from Menu to sub menu to Last level Menu,, But i Want to bind last level menu to menu.. how to do?

this is used to UserMenu Template,, if some user having access the Some Pages
if one USer Logged in and that user has allow to access some Pages MEans 1st it will bind Last Level 
menu to Menu ...one user logged in means it taken the session for that Userid ,, then in database that user having Menu or sub menu all details diaplayed,, my table like

```
SUB2MENUid  SubMenu2    SMenu2Id    SubMenuId   SubMenu MenuId  UserId  UserName
1               aa         1           1          A       2        3      abi
2               B1          4          3          B       2        3    abi
3   A2  3   1   A   2   3   abi 
4   II  19  7   I   3   3   abi
5   F1  17  6   F   3   3   abi
6   FF  16  6   F   3   3   abi
7   C2  9   3   C   2   3   abi
8   aa  1   1   A   2   1   Suresh
9   a1  2   1   A   2   1   Suresh
10  C2  9   3   C   2   1   Suresh
11  DD  10  4   D   3   1   Suresh
12  D2  12  4   D   3   1   Suresh
13  JJ  22  8   J   4   1   Suresh
14  J1  23  8   J   4   1   Suresh
15  LL  28  10  L   4   1   Suresh
16  MM  31  11  M   4   1   Suresh
17  I1  20  7   I   3   1   Suresh
18  FF  16  6   F   3   1   Suresh
19  BB  4   2   B   2   1   Suresh
20  B2  6   2   B   2   1   Suresh
21  A2  3   1   A   2   1   Suresh
22  B1  5   2   B   2   1   Suresh
23  CC  7   3   C   2   1   Suresh
24  C1  8   3   C   2   1   Suresh
25  D1  11  4   D   3   1   Suresh
26  EE  13  5   E   3   1   Suresh
27  E1  14  5   E   3   1   Suresh
28  E2  15  5   E   3   1   Suresh
29  F1  17  6   F   3   1   Suresh
30  F2  18  6   F   3   1   Suresh
31  II  19  7   I   3   1   Suresh
32  I2  21  7   I   3   1   Suresh
33  J2  24  8   J   4   1   Suresh
34  KK  25  9   K   4   1   Suresh
35  K1  26  9   K   4   1   Suresh
36  K2  27  9   K   4   1   Suresh
37  L1  29  10  L   4   1   Suresh
38  L2  30  10  L   4   1   Suresh
39  M1  32  11  M   4   1   Suresh
40  M2  33  11  M   4   1   Suresh
41  M2  33  11  M   4   3   saran
42  L2  30  10  L   4   3   saran
43  KK  25  9   K   4   3   saran
44  EE  13  5   E   3   3   saran
45  aa  1   1   A   2   2   sameer
46  a1  2   1   A   2   2   sameer
47  C1  8   3   C   2   2   sameer
48  KK  25  9   K   4   2   sameer
49  K1  26  9   K   4   2   sameer
50  L2  30  10  L   4   2   sameer
51  L1  29  10  L   4   2   sameer
52  D1  11  4   D   3   4   kavi
53  FF  16  6   F   3   4   kavi
54  B1  4   3   B   2   4   kavi
55  a1  2   1   A   2   4   kavi
56  EE  13  5   E   3   4   kavi
57  DD  10  4   D   3   4   kavi
58  F1  17  6   F   3   4   kavi
59  B2  6   2   B   2   4   kavi
```

. How to Do it...